# Difference between function $f$ in eval and dec of homomorphic authenticated encryption

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, authenticated-encryption, function-evaluation

In the homomorphic authenticated encryption, as described [1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/726.pdf), there are Eval and Dec PPT algorithms: 
[image: PPt algorithms]

In Eval, f is the function to be performed on the encrypted data. However, I need to know why it is used in Dec algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

The key-word "authenticated" mean that Dec is has not just a decrypting functionality. It should also check the validity of the computation made. that's why it takes as input the function $f$. Read more in details the paragraph "4.4 Authenticity".